# moto to test aws sts locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, moto

I would like to test my sts setup using moto locally.

**get_aws_temp_credentials.py**

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def assume_role(aws_arn=None, aws_session_name=None):
    if aws_arn is not None and aws_session_name is not None:
        try:
            local_session_name = aws_session_name[:64]
            client = boto3.client('sts', region_name=Constants.pubAwsRegion)
            response = client.assume_role(RoleArn=aws_arn,
                                          RoleSessionName=local_session_name,
                                          DurationSeconds=900)

            return response
        except ClientError as error:
            logger.info({"message": "get_aws_temp_credentails.py: Can not assume Role"})
            return 25


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assume_role()
```

**test_assume_role.py :**

```
import os
import pytest
from moto import mock_sts


@pytest.fixture
def aws_credentials():
    """Mocked AWS Credentials for moto."""
    os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'] = 'testing'


@pytest.fixture
def sts(aws_credentials):
    with mock_sts():
        yield boto3.client('sts', region_name=Constants.AwsRegion)


def test_temp_credentials(sts):
   from get_aws_temp_credentials import *
    response = assume_role(aws_arn=Constants.awsArn_to_assume_not_exists,
                           aws_session_name="My Dummy session")
    assert response == 25
```

As per [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) this should work. 
But it is not returning any resposne, neither it reacts to the `assume_role` call.